# Sparks enableHiveSupport

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Using Sparks2/java I have the spark-hive_2.11-2.0.1.jar in my class path but still get:  Error Unable to instantiate SparkSession with Hive support because Hive classes are not found.

```
SparkSession.enableHiveSupport()
```

Anything more needs done

Answer (score 0):

The only way this worked is to update Maven project, let Maven do its magic:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
     <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```